# Seq2Seq Model input shape

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, seq2seq

I'm a little lost with this code. I'm trying to create a seq2seq model and I think I have things all setup but I can't seem to figure out why I am getting the following error in the train method

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "functional_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 24, 9), found shape=(None, 9)
```

My code is the following:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import sys
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Seq2SeqLSTM:

    def __init__(self,Train):

        self.TrainClass = Train

      
    
    def StartModel(self):


        XTrain, YTrain, XTest, YTest = self.GetTrainingData()
   
        
        self.DefineModel(XTrain,YTrain)
        self.CompileModel()
        
       
        # Train the model
        self.Train(XTrain, YTrain, YTrain)

        Predictions = self.Predict(XTest[1], YTest[0]) 


    def DefineModel(self,XTrain,YTrain):


        self.InputSeqLength                 = len(XTrain)
        self.InputDim                       = len(XTrain[0])
        self.HiddenUnits                    = 64

        self.EncoderInputs                  = Input(shape = (self.InputSeqLength, self.InputDim))
        self.DecoderInputs                  = Input(shape = (self.InputSeqLength, self.InputDim))
        
        
        self.Model                          = self.BuildModel()
        

    def BuildModel(self):

        EncoderLSTM                         = LSTM(self.HiddenUnits, return_state = True)
        EncoderOutputs, StateH, StateC      = EncoderLSTM(self.EncoderInputs)
        EncoderStates                       = [StateH, StateC]

        DecoderLSTM                         = LSTM(self.HiddenUnits, return_sequences = True, return_state = True)
        DecoderOutputs, _, _                = DecoderLSTM(self.DecoderInputs, initial_state = EncoderStates)

        DecoderDense                        = Dense(1, activation  = 'linear')
        DecoderOutputs                      = DecoderDense(DecoderOutputs)

        PModel = Model([self.EncoderInputs, self.DecoderInputs], DecoderOutputs)
        
        return PModel

    def CompileModel(self):

        self.Model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')

    def Train(self, XEncoder, XDecoder, Y, BatchSize = 32, Epochs = 10):


        self.History = self.Model.fit([XEncoder, XDecoder], Y, batch_size = BatchSize, epochs = Epochs, verbose = 1)

    
    def Predict(self, XEncoder, XDecoder):

        return self.Model.predict([XEncoder, XDecoder])

    def PlotLoss(self):

       
        plt.plot(self.History.history['loss'])
        plt.legend(["This is my legend"], fontsize="x-large")
        plt.title('Model Loss')
        plt.ylabel('Loss')
        plt.xlabel('Epoch')
        plt.savefig('loss.png')

    def SplitTrainData(self,X, Y, TestSize = 0.2):
       
        SplitIndex = int(len(X) * (1 - TestSize))
        
        XTrain, XTest = X[:SplitIndex], X[SplitIndex:]
        YTrain, YTest = Y[:SplitIndex], Y[SplitIndex:]
        
        return XTrain, YTrain, XTest, YTest


    def GetTrainingData(self):

     
    
        X       = []
        Y       = []

        Data    = self.TrainClass.ProcessData()

       
        for I in Data:
            
            X1 = []
            Y1 = [] 

            for J in I[0]:
                X1.append([J])

            for K in I[1]:
                Y1.append([K])

            X.append(np.array(X1))
            Y.append(np.array(Y1))


        X = np.array(X)
        Y = np.array(Y)

        self.X = X 
        self.Y = Y

        return self.SplitTrainData(X,Y)
```

My training(XTrain, YTrain) data has a shape of (24,9,1). Y has a shape of (24, 12, 1) which is correct. I don't understand why my shape is changing to (None, 9). Do I need to reshape the data or is it some other issue I am not realizing?